# Are radius and diameters lengths or line segments itself?

Tags: terminology, circles

For a circle, I generally remember radius and diameters as length of line segments only. Former is the length of line segment connecting center of the circle and any point on the circle and the latter is the length of the line segment (chord) connecting any two points on the circle and passes through the origin of the circle.

But, in some math sites, authors refer radius and diameter as to corresponding line segments rather than their lengths.

Which sense is correct?

Comment: Heard of the term "radii"? Considering Radius as the length of line segment joining the center of a circle and any point on it, what would radii mean, being plural of radius because the length is constant. Radius, diameters and chords of a circle are line segments first. While chord length is always different from chord, length of radius and diameter is often referred to as radius and diameter itself like, radius = 2 units, diameter = 4 units. The use of these two terms as lengths more common in coordinate geometry whereas in elementary geometry, they are considered as line segment, generally.

Comment: One more general convention can be seen in the same manner. We write, suppose AB is the line segment joining A and B. Then in the very next step, we write AB= 5 units. (Just a sec ago AB was a line segment and now a line segment is equal to some length). Okay, AB is the line segment, still. But in the equation AB=5 units, AB means the distance between points A and B which is another convention. After this, we go further and write AB $\perp$ CD. (Is a length perpendicular to something? No, that's the line segment). Similarly we write radius = OA (line segment), OA= 10 units , radius=10 (length)

Comment: I'm perfectly comfortable saying "Let $OA$ be a radius of a circle of radius $7$." I think it's easy enough to tell from context what an author means. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That statement seems equivocal. I would say "Let $OA$ be a radius of a circle of length $7$". That said, see https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/defI15.html . Euclid defines the diameter of the circle to be a straight line going through the center of the circle. He doesn't define the radius but it is usually meant to denote the ray from the center of the circle.

Comment: @John, how about, "Let $C$ be a circle of radius $7$, and let $OA$ be a radius of that circle" ?

Comment: @Gerry That seems better but we are still using radius to mean two different things in the same sentence.

Comment: @John, we do that all the time. Bear with me while I deal with this bear. Can I have a can of soda? Time flies like an arrow, fruit flies like a banana. Why is this a problem? Do you know how many meanings the word "normal" has in mathematics?